# JPA EntityGraph is not working; Always loading related collections

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb

I am trying to get named entity graphs to work properly.  Basically, I have a Customer who can have zero or more Addresses.  When I query to get a list of Customers, I want the customer's fields, but not the associated Addresses.  When I query for a particular Customer, I want its fields and all of the associated Addresses.  So, I've been trying to use named entity graphs because they seem to address this situation.  I created one to get basic information, and another that gets everything.  Unfortunately, when I use either graph, I still always get everything.  I am sure that I am making a simple mistake, but I cannot seem to find it.  I'd appreciate your help to figure out my error.  The relevant code follows...

Thank you for your time and advise,
Mike

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ENTITIES
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")})

@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(
        name="previewCustomerEntityGraph", 
        attributeNodes={
            @NamedAttributeNode("id"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("displayAs"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("rowVersion")
        }
    ),
    @NamedEntityGraph(
        name="fullCustomerEntityGraph", 
        attributeNodes={
            @NamedAttributeNode("id"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("displayAs"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("rowVersion"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "addressCollection", subgraph = "addressCollection")
        },
        subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(
            name = "addressCollection", 
            attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("id"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("displayAs"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("rowVersion")
            }
        )
    )
})
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "DisplayAs")
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false)
    private String displayAs;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "Name")
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=true)
    private String name;    

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false)
    @Column(name = "RowVersion")
    @Version
    private Timestamp rowVersion;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Address> addressCollection;

//@XmlTransient
public Collection<Address> getAddressCollection() {
    return addressCollection;
}

public void setAddressCollection(Collection<Address> addressCollection) {
    this.addressCollection = addressCollection;
}

    // Object methods have been removed to save space
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Address.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a")})
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "RowVersion")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=true)
    private Date rowVersion;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "DisplayAs")    
    @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=true)
    private String displayAs;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customerId;

    // Object methods have been removed to save space
}





/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// QUERIES
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    protected T find(Object id) {                   
        // Filter to only return entities belonging to the tenant.       

        EntityGraph eg = getEntityManager().getEntityGraph("fullCustomerEntityGraph");

        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> from = cq.from(entityClass);        
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> select = cq.select(from);      
        cq.where(cb.and(
                cb.equal(from.<T>get("id"), id)
        ));

        javax.persistence.TypedQuery<T> tq = getEntityManager().createQuery(select);

        tq.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", eg);

        return getSingleResultOrNull(tq);
    }

    protected List<T> findAll() {       
        // Filter to only return entities belonging to the tenant.

        EntityGraph eg = getEntityManager().getEntityGraph("previewCustomerEntityGraph");

        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> from = cq.from(entityClass);        
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> select = cq.select(from);       
        javax.persistence.TypedQuery<T> tq = getEntityManager().createQuery(select);

        tq.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", eg);

        return tq.getResultList();
    }

    protected T getSingleResultOrNull(javax.persistence.TypedQuery<T> query) {
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        List<T> list = query.getResultList();
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return list.get(0);
    }
```

Comment: Try something simplier: `SELECT c FROM Customer c` to fetch only Customers and `SELECT c FROM Customer c left join fetch c.addressCollection` to return everything you need.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for your response.  I commented out the entity graph annotations and created two named queries, as you've specified.  Unfortunately, I still am getting the same results as before... :(  I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks! Mike

Comment: How do you know it is returning everything at once? Are you monitoring the SQLs? Please post the code that uses the find* methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The way that I am determining the query's results is by what is serialized via json back to Fiddler, so I am never directly calling the getAddressList() method, which would load the lazy collection. I am using Jackson Json for serialization and Jaxb annotations. I suspect that the issue involves Jaxb/Jackson annotations, but, after a few days, I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: All I want to do is return a Customer's data from JAX-RS to Fiddler when using findAll(). When using Find(id), I want to return the Customer's data and all of its Addresses. I am new to JPA, but it seems that named entity graphs are a good way to accomplish these goals. Since I am using JAX-RS, I hope to keep the findAll() and Find(id) methods generic. I would really appreciate your help to sort out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I've changed the Address collection to the following:

@XmlElement
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "addressCollection")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Address> addressCollection;

I am using Fidder for the following testing...

Now, when I findAll(), I get just the Customer info, which is perfect. When I find(9), I get the Customer info and Addresses, which is perfect! But, when I do a findAll() again, I get back the Customers and Addresses, which is bad.

Comment: The JAX-RS service is the standard one that is generated by NetBeans/Maven, and I've generated the entities from the database and also generated the facades. So, I do not understand why we are having this behavior.

Here are the details:

Restarted GlassFish 4

Launched the JAX-RS Service with debug

In Fiddler:

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Serializing/customers
Got only the list of Customers; No Address info; GREAT!

http://localhost:8080/Serializing/customers
Got only the list of Customers; No Address info; GREAT!

http://localhost:8080/Serializing/customers/9
Got the Customer's data and Addresses; GREAT!

http://localhost:8080/Serializing/customers/10
Got the Customer's data and Addresses; GREAT!

http://localhost:8080/Serializing/customers
ARGGG! Got the list of Customers and Addresses! BAD!

Shut down the JAX-RS Service

Launched the JAX-RS Service with debug

Same results as before... Repeatable.

Comment: It might be easier if you see the entire sample project that I am using, so it can be downloaded from the following URL:

http://9ae324bdea12456e8940-80de7026d6700afa799b216d7fcde2cf.r39.cf2.rackcdn.com/Serializing.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer is calling `getAddressCollection`.

Note that `@XmlTransient` is commented on address list. Place this annotation back and try again.

In this case auto serialization will allways avoid the list. If you need to return the full graph somewhere else I recommend writing your own serialization logic or create a `Value Object` to hold exactly what you need and let serializer do the job.

Comment: Hi Ivan,  Thank you for your suggestion.  I uncommented @XmlTransient, but we are having the same results.  What is strange is that everything is fine when I query findAll(), but after loading a specific Customer via find(id), any calls to findAll() return the customers and addresses.  I am leaning in the direction that you've suggested...  Create DTOs and return explicitly what I want.  I was hoping to avoid it, but I am getting tired of wrestling with something that should be easy. :)  Thanks, again, for your help!  Mike

Comment: In fact you are detaching Hibernate annotation logic from JSON serialization logic, it's not rare to see them collapse and led to weird results. So it's not bad at all and gives you fine grained control. I also suggest you to monitor the generated SQLs commands.

Comment: I am in the process of implementing DTOs for testing...  It should be pretty easy.  I am going to use Orika for mapping...  Thanks again for the help!